# JOIN multiple tables sharing the same Primary Key

Tags: sql-server, join, ssms, union

I have 4 tables that share the same PK `usercode`. I need to retrieve various columns from each table based on the usercode. Eg:

- T1 (**usercode**, A1, A2, A3, ...)
- T2 (**usercode**, B1, B2, B3,...)
- T3 (**usercode**, C1, C2, C3,...)
- T4 (**usercode**, D1, D2, D3,...)

I tried the following:

```
SELECT A1, A2, B3, B4, C2, D1, D4 
FROM T1 A 
JOIN T2 B ON a.usercode = b.usercode
JOIN T3 C ON b.usercode = c.usercode 
JOIN T4 D ON c.usercode = d.usercode
```

When I do this, I get duplicate results. What's the best way to do this?

Also, whenever I use `UNION` I get an error

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric

I'm going crazy about this, any lead will help! Thanks

Comment: A primary key column cannot reasonably generate duplicates. Please provide sample data, current and desired results to demonstrate your use case.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. I vote to close.

Comment: Post the table schemas.  You are getting a data type mismatch when trying to UNION.  You will need to identify which field is mismatched do something like to_char() or to_number() to cast a value to the matching data type.  You should be able to SELECT DISTINCT to remove the duplicates, possibly.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:
I am hoping your suercodes have the same type

```
SELECT A1,A2,B3,B4,C2,D1,D4 
FROM 
(select usercode from T1 union select usercode from T2 
union select usercode from T3 union select usercode from T4)u
JOIN T1 A ON u.usercode = a.usercode
JOIN T2 B ON u.usercode = b.usercode
JOIN T3 C ON u.usercode = c.usercode 
JOIN T4 D ON u.usercode = d.usercode
```